# Chrome onChange event not firing for cleared field after form reset

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

It seems that chrome is not firing a change event when a text field has been cleared just after the form has been reset.

Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
    function doChange() {
      document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = 'Field changed to:[' + event.target.value + ']'; 
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type='text' value='test1' onChange='doChange();'/>
    <input type='text' value='test2' onChange='doChange();'/>
    <button type='reset'>Reset</button>
    <div id='info'></div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/ahc6fpuw/ for the test bed.

Is this a know issue and if so is does anyone have a work around?

Add steps to create the problem:
1 Enter some text into the first text field
2 Press the reset button (that resets the text correctly)
3 Select all the text in the first field and press the delete key
4 Press the tab key to move to the second text field.  The doChange function should have been called but it is not.

Comment: I'm not seeing the issue, or I don't understand the steps you're taking.

Comment: I see that your reset button is changing the input text elements but isn't triggering the onchange event but why do you have two text inputs? only one can be used so i'm confused to why you would have two...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change: _“The change event is fired […] when a change to the element's value **is committed by the user**. Unlike the input event, the change event **is not necessarily fired for each change to an element's value**.”_

Comment: The only reason for the second input is to test changing the focus.  The issue is that if the reset button is pressed and then one of the text fields is cleared (highlight the text and press delete or backspace) and the click on the second text field, no change event is fired (even though the user cleared the field).

Answer (score 1):

Reset gives the default value to the html element, in your case it is "test1" & "test2", so even if you do reset it will show the "test1" & "test2".

Answer (score 0):

The reset button doesn't clears the text inside the form it just resets to given value.
Try placeholder instead value attribute

---

```
<form>
    <input type='text' placeholder='test1' onChange='doChange();'/>
    <input type='text' placeholder='test2' onChange='doChange();'/>
    <button type='reset'>Reset</button>
    <div id='info'></div>
  </form>
```